# Django: how to simplify calls for rendering templates from subdirectory

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I have django project with a couple applications. To be able use templates with common names (like `index`, `menu`, ..., `page1`, `page2`) in more then one of them I adopted this schema:

```
app1/
    templates/
        app1/
            page1.html
            page2.html
app2/
    templates/
        app2/
            page1.html
            page2.html
```

and in views I use it like that:

```
def myview(request): # in app1
    context={'name':'John', 'surname':'Lennon'}
    return render(request,"app1/page1.html",context)
```

or

```
 def myview(request): # in app2
    context={'tool':'hammer', 'size':'big'}
    return render(request,"app2/page1.html",context)
```

it works, but I have to write the full app name (`app1/`, `app2/`) in each and every render (and no app uses templates from other app or just from templates/ (except the project itself) ) and the apps names are actually long like 10-17 characters (not short as `app1`, `app2`)

**The question:**  is there a way to do it better, that each applications render would not default to  `templates/` but to `templates/app1/`, `templates/app2/` and so, respectively?

Thanks for all suggestions

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution is, you can declare the path on top of the app or in settings.py and use that variable in entire script, for example:

```
path1 = "app1/templates/"
path2 = "app2/templates/"

def myview(request): # in app1
    context={'name':'John', 'surname':'Lennon'}
    return render(request,path1+"page1.html",context)

def myview(request): # in app2
    context={'tool':'hammer', 'size':'big'}
    return render(request,path2+"page1.html",context)
```

This can also reduce the typing efforts.